# Image does not wrap with the right of the text

Tags: graphics, pdftex, wrapfigure

I'm using the `wrapfig` package to align my image to the right of my text for a section I'm writing for my dissertation. For privacy, I -snipped- away the text I have put in.

The LaTeX page I am writing in for this question is imported into my main document. The document compiles with the warning:

`Warning: wrapfigure used inside a conflicting environment`

The page is as follows:

```
\begin{flushleft}

-snipped-

\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{img/placeholder}
    \caption{This is a figure caption.}
\end{wrapfigure}

-snipped-

\begin{itemize}
    \item ...
    \item ...
    \item ...
\end{itemize}

\end{flushleft}
```

I looked at other questions and apparently itemize causes issues. I tried removing it and I still had the same issue where the image was pushed to the bottom of the page. For reference the image is `300x300` pixels.

Comment: wrapfig does not work if around a list such as itemize which is a well documented limitation in the file. If you have a document that is not using a list in that way but not working, please post a small complete document that allows someone to debug the problem. (you can use `example-image` as the image as a test image of that name is in the standard tex distributions)  note that `flushleft` is also a list environment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I removed the `flushleft` and it works! However, I have indentations in the paragraphs; which is why I used it to remove them. Is there a way around this?

Comment: do you want the text to be justified (even right margin apart from the wrapfig) or ragged with differerent length lines. `flusheft` is mostly about having ragged right margin, no indent is more or less a side effect. but you can use `\raggedright` for a non-list version of the settings `flushleft` uses.

Comment: You can replace your snipped text with  the lipsum or blindtext package.  The important thing is just how much text is there and how big the image is, which you code fragment doesn't even begin to addreas.